# How can i make a duplicate of a line in file in python?

Tags: python, text

I want to read a text.txt file that has some random text, i want to create a program to make it read it line by line and if it finds specific text to make a duplicate of the line.

i have managed to find the line i want to duplicate with the below code
read line by line of a file like
original file

> test copy test

so i made the below code

```
with open("text.txt",'r+') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
        if 'copy' in line:
            x="copy"
            f.write(x)
            f.write(x)
```

the expected result would be

> test copy copy test

but instead i get

> test copy test copycopy

Comment: Are you trying to modify the line you found the word on, or are you trying to create a new line with the modifications on it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
Your desired result is unclear.

Comment: You also suffer from trying to write a file *while* you are reading it.  Work through a secondary tutorial on files to learn how the file descriptor works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> test copy test

is already in the file and won't move... Note that you are writing "copy" two times in your script. You write in the end of the file. That's why you are getting.

> test copy test copycopy

You find "copy" once, then write twice but in the end. Also, you aren't using a blankspace when printing "copy".

My suggestion: create a new file, read from the original, write in the new. If you find the word you are looking for, write twice. Then keep going all the way to the end.

Comment: thanks for the answer i think i will go with this aprroach

Answer (score 0):

if the following doesn't work, just set line as a string.
But I think this is what you're looking for.

```
if 'copy' in line:
    x = line.replace('copy', 'copy copy')
    f.write(x)
```

You could simplify with the following

```
if 'copy' in line:
    f.write(line.replace('copy', 'copy copy'))
```